# Auto Drag Element After Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to automatically drag some elements (e.g. `<img>`) to specified location (x, y) after page load? How to do it? I'm sorry I don't have any code, I look around but nothing similar to this problem. Please give me some directions in this matter, thanks.

Comment: I guess it's something like that

Comment: @shankshera view the fiddle in my answer below and see if that does what you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mover').animate({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }, 2000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div id="mover" style=" position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; border: 1px solid black; width:200px; height:200px">
    TEXT
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YM3Bt/2/)

Comment: This is the closest thing that I could get to with 'automatically drag'.  This takes an absolute positioned div and animates its top and left properties to an arbitrary number, in this case 0.  The effect is something flying to the left when the DOM is ready.